# How would I implement a "Keep me logged in" feature in Flask?

Tags: python, session, flask

By default Flask ends a session when the user closes the browser.  How can I keep the session around longer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#sessions

Look at the "permanent" tag here to keep the session alive for 31 days.